# Convert a div and contents inside it to image

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have a DIV container which has some text, background-image, image. I need to convert that whole DIV contents into image and save.

I have googled it around but could not find the perfect answer. some are giving answers that uses a windows application , but i need it on a web platform .

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: @Tats_innit Do you think the code may help?

Comment: In JavaScript or server-side?

Comment: Hiya @VisioN it says he/she has a DIV with some image and css;it will be good to see the whole setup before I can comment anything! Further this is tagged as Jquery or Javascript just keen to see the code, anyhow if you reckon it will not then its cool bruv!

Comment: You can see that it should help you ...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825262/best-way-to-convert-a-div-to-image-using-either-php-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you have to do that in the client side, so you should take a look at the toDataURL method of the canvas.

If you don't know, the canvas support text and image.

Example and little library at this link:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: @Chris Gessler: as far as i know in java script only window.print() method is there and it is always problematic with background images and css styles

Comment: thanks 4 ur help ... but the issue is with compatibility... when will be ie banned?

Answer (score 1):

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Does't support IE though. Looks solid other than that.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, with modification to the code here http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html you could perform the required `screenshot` :)